# Parsing a CSV string and using elements of the string for computation- homework

Tags: string, parsing, csv, fileoutputstream

I am very new to java, and this is homework. Any direction would be appreciated.
The assignment is to read an external text file and then parse that file to produce a new file.
The external file looks something like this:

```
2             //number of lines in the file
3,+,4,*,2,-.   
5,*,2,T,1,+
```

I have to read this file and produce an output that takes the preceding int value and prints the following character (skipping the comma). So the output would look like this:

```
+++****--
*****TT+
```

I have tried to setup my code using two methods. The first to read the external file (passed as a parameter) which, as long as there is a next line, will call a second method, processLine, to parse the line. This is where I am lost. I can't figure out how this method should be structured so it reads the line and interprets the token values as either ints or chars, and then executes code based on those values.
I am only able to use what we have covered in class, so no external libraries, just the basics.

```
public static void numToImageRep(File input, File output) //rcv file
    throws FileNotFoundException {  
        Scanner read = new Scanner(input);
        while(read.hasNextLine()){ //read file line by line
        String data = read.nextLine();
        processLine(data); //pass line for processing
        }
    }
public static void processLine(String text){  //incomplete, all falls apart here.
    Scanner process = new Scanner(text);
    while(process.hasNext()){
        if(process.hasNextInt()){
            int multi = process.nextInt();
            }
        if(process.hasNext()==','){



    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this method can be a simple example that can do the job:

```
public static String processLine(String text){
    String result = "";
    String[] splitted = text.split(",");
    int remaining = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<splitted.length;i+=2)
    {
        remaining = (Integer.parseInt(splitted[i]));
        while( remaining-- >0)
            result += splitted[i+1];
    }
        return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wound up merging your solution into a single method (no need to call a separate method as I had originally thought). Very much appreciated.

Comment: sure, no problem happy that i could be of help :)